# Trigger BroadcastReceiver when low battery in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, battery, batterymanager

I'm trying to trigger the broadcast receiver whenever the battery is low irrespective of whether the app is in the foreground/killed. The Broadcast's onReceive() is never been called. I've followed the [Official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring#MonitorLevel) & I've gone through almost all solutions none of them worked for me. Please let me know any other solution. Thanks :)

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<receiver
      android:name=".worker.LowBatteryBroadcastReceiver"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**BroadcastReceiver.class**

```
class LowBatteryBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
        val level: Int = intent!!.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0)
        Timber.d("LowBatteryBroadcastReceiver - level: %d", level)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I issued the same problem, solved it by explicitly registering the receiver in my code (without removing from the manifest, but it should be ininfluent). I think it's related with the changes from SDK 26 where implicit broadcasts are no longer allowed excepts for certain types of broadcasts in which `BATTERY_LOW` alas doesn't belong to.

```
batteryLevel = new BatteryLevel();
mContext.registerReceiver(batteryLevel, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW));
```

Here's [reference](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts) to the official documentation